# Access API returns JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Javascript to decode a vehicles VIN number via an API. The returned message looks like this:

```
{Count: 116, Message: "Results returned successfully", SearchCriteria: "VIN(s): 60540kjhkjhkj5885", Results: Array(1)}
```

I need to know how to access the returned array in results.

This is my current Javascript:

```
   // Decode VIN Number
function post_VIN_decode() {
    var vinNumber = $('#id_vin_number').val();
    console.log("VIN Decode Sent") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevinvalues/" + vinNumber + "?format=json", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};

$('#id_vin_number').keyup(function(e){
    if($("#id_vin_number").val().length >= 17){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("VIN Decode started")  // sanity check
        post_VIN_decode();
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What *"returned array"*? The `Results` property? I'd add `dataType: 'json'` then you should be able to use `json.Results`

Comment: "Results: Array(1)}"

Comment: `// log the returned json to the console` comment is a lie, as is the variable name `json`. What you report is not what is returned by the request. The request from your example is [this](https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevinvalues/60540kjhkjhkj5885?format=json), and you can see the returned JSON in a browser. What you reported is a copy-paste from a console after executing your code, which is not JSON (a string), but console-presented view of the decoded JavaScript objects - I suggest you change the lying variable name `json` to `data`, and access results as `data.Results`.

Comment: So it is an object, what is the problem accessing its property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your success try:

```
success : function(json) {
    console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console

    $.each(json.Results, function( index, value ) {
        console.log( index + ": " + value );
    });

    console.log("Or just the first index: " + json.Results[0]);
},
```

Comment: jQuery will have already parsed the JSON response into an object. There's no need to parse it again

Comment: True, changed answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to iterate through the array and do some processing on the elements, [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is what you need here.

```
...

success: function(json) {
  json.Results.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item, index);
  });
},

...
```

Refer to the link in my answer to read more about this function and examples.